# Trying to understand the "big picture" with certs, TLS and win32api

Tags: winapi, tls1.2

I have a hardware device given to me by a manufacturer.  The device is listening on port 5001 for incoming connection requests.  It has a SSL/TLS certificate installed on the device.  I have Python script that successfully connects, handshakes and communicates with the device. The device is on the Internet and I can share the Python and cert if you want to give it a try.

Thing is our company needs to use simple C calls to the win32api to talk to the board.  It's just how our thing works - it is windows service written over the last 20 years.  All we want to do is let this new hardware connect to us.

The manufacturer has given us a "comm.cert" file, I think it is a "PEM" file.  It has three things in it, a CERT, a TRUSTED CERT and a PRIVATE KEY.  We want to use the file and not "install it" on the machine.

Using CertOpenStore then CertFindCertificateInStore I can get a Cert Context handle.
I can call CertGetNameString and see the correct name of the cert from the file.

I can't successfuly call CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey

My first question: Is CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey the correct thing to be calling?

I have been though a bunch of books and done lots of googling and I am a bit lost.

I beleve the goal is to call CertSetCertificateContextProperty or WinHttpSetOption but that is where my confusion sets in.

So before I start showing lots of (perhaps pointless) code I would love to understand the steps needed to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your first step is to identify which SSL/TLS library you want to use.  Here are a few links: https://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:win32_ssl:txt, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-secure-socket-extensions.  SUGGESTION: start off with a  minimal "hello world" client, just to verify you can "connect".

Comment: Is it a client cert or is it the server cert? What does the python script look like?

Comment: Thank you,  I think I am doing good with WinHttp.  I need to match the api to the cert in the PEM file.  I have a cert context (a handle to the contest structure) and can confirm I got the right cert.  It's the KEY that has me lost.
Have tried CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey....  I need to get an explanation of the concepts.  Then the code should be fairly easy.

Comment: I am using it on the client side. It is a file with three things in it.  A cert, a trusted cert and a key.  Three sections.   I'm not sure how to show the Python code.  Can I attach it here?   CertOpenStore with CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME_A can open it and read it in to a cert context structure.

Comment: `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` query `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` for get ContainerName where private key is stored. but in your case private key not stored in any container and certificate context returned by `CertOpenStore` on pem file - have no any properties. `CertOpenStore ` at all have very restricted functional on pem. you need manually open/parse pem, add private key to some container. add certificate to store and set `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` for it

Comment: Wow, thanks RbMm.  I am going to have to read your comment very carefully!  Would this all be much easier if I were to import the cert into the store on my machine and then go looking for it in the store?  Am I making things unnecessarily difficult trying to grab it from a file?

Comment: you need first pre-process pem file. exctract private key from it and store it in some container ( NCryptImportKey ). store certificate in some store ( say "My") and set `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` with container info. you can do all this programatically, or convert first pem to pfx and install cert/key from pfx by ui

Comment: big picture - certificate not containing private key, and even any "pointer" to it. from pure certificat impossible get private key. how ?! but when certificate save in store - store save not only certificate itself, but collection of properties, which is not part of certificate. so when you store cert it store - you can set property on it - where get private key ( `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID `). exist also `CERT_PVK_FILE_PROP_ID`, but if i not mistake, `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` not use it

Comment: Either edit the python script code into your question or if it's too large then use something like pastebin.

Comment: The Python code only proves the task can be accomplished.  It doesn't use the win32api.  Our requirement is it must use win32api.  I have been reading and googling and have yet to find an example of discussion of the correct way to accomplish this. Most suggest something along the lines of:

WinHttpOpen
WinHttpConnect
WinHttpOpenRequest
CertOpenStore
CertFindCertificateInStore
WinHttpSendRequest

So far - and there have been many tests...
No luck.

Again, before I dive into code I would love to hear a discussion on what win32api functions in what order would get results.

Comment: Its not clear to me what the task actually is. If all you need to do is make a plain old https connection then that's easy and the talk about the cert is irrelevant. If you need to provide the hardware with a client cert during the connection (or if it's not https at all) then that's more work. The python script will clarify what the task actually is.

Comment: Hi Luke - The task is to have our current Windows product (which is a Windows service) be able to connect to the device on the Internet (TCP IP) establish a secure handshake then upgrade to a WebSocket.  If this were not using TLS it would be easy.  Just open the socket and chat away.  But I have to authenticate.  Our current stuff uses encrypted TCP IP this thing requires the entire connection uses TLS.  I can't figure it out using win32api.  Things that do work are not using win32api.  Client says must be win32api.  I have lots of books and google and chatGPT but so far no dice.

Comment: RbMm left some interesting remarks but I don't understand them.  I am not sure where the properties he is referring to are.  The python code is able to simply open the cert file and make the connection.  People have said "show the python code" but it is calling libraries etc that I can't use.  Also it is not using win32API, I looked.  I suspect they are using open AI.

Comment: Of course the python code will be using different libraries, but it will help clarify what exactly you need to replicate. I posted an answer based on assumptions I've made that are likely correct but could be wrong; seeing the python code would verify if we're on the right path.

Comment: Thanks Luke - I will figure out how to post the code.  Is it ok to put a url here?  I

Comment: Thanks Luke - Look here - https://eicx.com/s_122/

Comment: I get a 404 on the python files and aspsdk.lic

Comment: Sorry, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to do plain old HTTPS then upgrade to websocket. I don't really know much about websockets, but WinHTTP does seem to have support for them via WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade() et al.

As far as the HTTPS goes, it's a simple combination of WinHttpOpen(), WinHttpConnect(), WinHttpOpenRequest(),  WinHttpSendRequest(), and WinHttpReceiveResponse().

I'm assuming the hardware is using a private or self-signed cert, in which case it won't be trusted by WinHTTP. To verify that, you can [set some flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/option-flags#winhttp_option_security_flags) in WinHTTP to trust any certificate and see if you can connect to the hardware. If so, and if you want to verify the expected certificate is being used, then you can load the certificate from the file into an in-memory certificate store and tell WinHTTP to trust it.

**Update**

So there's two primary components to this:

1. Initialize the security context
2. Perform the connection

I'll cover the second component first since that's easier. The sequence of calls looks like the following:

1. `WinHttpOpen()`
2. `WinHttpConnect()`
3. `WinHttpOpenRequest()`
4. `WinHttpSetOption(WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, CertContext)`
5. `WinHttpSetOption(WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID)`
6. `WinHttpSetOption(WINHTTP_OPTION_UPGRADE_TO_WEB_SOCKET)`
7. `WinHttpSendRequest()`
8. `WinHttpReceiveResponse()`
9. `WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade()`

The `WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` option sets the client certificate that you're going to use to authenticate with the sever; I'll go over how to obtain this in the next section.

The `WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS` option tells WinHttp to ignore a couple things:

- The `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA` flag tells WinHttp to ignore untrusted root certificate authorities. We need to set this flag because the server certificate is self-signed and it is not in a trusted certificate root store. You could avoid this by installing it in a trusted certificate root store, but you don't want to so this is how to get around that.
- The `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID` flag tells WinHttp to ignore an invalid common name in the certificate. We need to set this flag because we're connecting by IP address and the certificate specifies a DNS name. Maybe in your environment the server is reachable by the appropriate DNS name, in which case you could remove this flag.

The `WINHTTP_OPTION_UPGRADE_TO_WEB_SOCKET` option tells WinHttp that you intend to upgrade to a websocket after making the connection.

The `WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade()` call performs the websocket upgrade.

Assuming all of the previous calls succeed, you can then use `WinHttpWebSocketSend()` and `WinHttpWebSocketReceive()` to transmit data over the websocket.

The Python code seems to be performing additional encryption over the websocket which seems redundant, but I suppose that's just how the device works. I only took it as far as opening a websocket; I did not attempt to actually implement the communication protocol.

As far as initializing the security context, it's a bit more complicated. You've got the certificate and private key in a PEM bundle. You need to convert them into formats that CryptoAPI operates with and load them into the appropriate contexts. CryptoAPI can decode PEM data, but (as far as I know) it can only do one item at a time. So you need to parse the PEM bundle and break it up into individual objects.

If you look in the `comm.crt` file you'll see three items: `CERTIFICATE`, `TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`, and `PRIVATE KEY`. For a client certificate you only care about the `CERTIFICATE` and `PRIVATE KEY` objects. You need to parse these sections out of the file, including the `BEGIN` and `END` headers, and process each section individually.

For each item, the first step is to decode it from base64 to binary using `CryptStringToBinary(CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER)`

For the certificate, you then need to call `CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING)`. This will give you the `CertContext` that you need to pass to WinHttp.

For the private key, you then need to call `CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY)`. This gives you a `CRYPT_PRIVATE_KEY_INFO` struct that contains information about the private key. You then need to call `CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY)`. This gives you a a private key blob. Finally, you need to call `CryptImportKey()` to import the private key into a key container, from which CryptoAPI can access it. You create the key container by calling `CryptAcquireContext()`.

The last piece is linking the certificate context with the private key so that CryptoAPI can find it. For this you need to call `CertSetCertificateContextProperty(CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID)` passing a `CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO` struct specifying the key container into which you loaded the private key.

I'm probably glossing over some things so let me know if something's not clear.

Comment: I have basically been doing what you are saying.  Except your "set some flags" is something new.  I will give that a try.  I also have CertOpenStore, CertFindCertificateInStore, CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey - but the flags thing is new.  Thanks!!   ALSO -  "in-memory certificate store"  THAT IS NEW TOO!  I have to go read up on that!!  BTW I don't have enough points to vote your answer up but you have given me the best advice in 5 days.

Comment: Ok, so it's sending a client certificate which makes it a bit more difficult and the Windows APIs aren't really geared towards working with PEM files directly so there's a lot of low-level setup that needs to be done. Regardless, I managed to clobber together some code that manages to successfully connect to the server and open a websocket. I need some time to clean and refactor to get something more digestible.

Comment: Luke: That is fantastic.  You also brought up a point that I had not considered - the fact that it is a "client" cert.  That device can act as a client or server.  It had to be a client so it could be reached over the Internet with a static IP.  In production it would be calling home - initiating the conversations - so would it be calling a server at that point and would the same certs be used?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, perhaps it has the correct certificate for calling home to a server.  The device is brand new so we are just starting to figure it out.